# How to create new woo-commerce order under particular customer?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating new woocommerce order by using this function `WC()->checkout()->create_order($order_data);` The order created under guest user. I would like create the order under existing customer as I can pass customer id. check below for my order data

```
array(
    'order' => array(
        'payment_details' => array(
            'method_id' => 'bacs',
            'method_title' => 'Direct Bank Transfer',
            'paid' => true
        ),
        'billing_address' => array(
            'first_name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Doe',
            'address_1' => '969 Market',
            'address_2' => '',
            'city' => 'San Francisco',
            'state' => 'CA',
            'postcode' => '94103',
            'country' => 'US',
            'email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
            'phone' => '(555) 555-5555'
        ),
        'shipping_address' => array(
            'first_name' => 'John',
            'last_name' => 'Doe',
            'address_1' => '969 Market',
            'address_2' => '',
            'city' => 'San Francisco',
            'state' => 'CA',
            'postcode' => '94103',
            'country' => 'US'
        ),
        'customer_id' => 114,
        'line_items' => array(
            array(
                'product_id' => 546,
                'quantity' => 2
            ),
            array(
                'product_id' => 613,
                'quantity' => 1,
                'variations' => array(
                    'pa_color' => 'Black'
                )
            )
        ),
        'shipping_lines' => array(
            array(
                'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
                'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
                'total' => 10
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: which hook your are using for create order?

Comment: you need to add user_id otherwise its show guest order